# eol unix to windows in command line .bat batch

Tags: command-line, batch-file, converters, eol

I am trying to convert text file eol to windows format from unix on windows xp machine using command line (batch file). how do I do that? what is the command for that? thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can find some `dos2unix` utility on your machine.

Comment: Or `unix2dos` eg from http://sourceforge.net/projects/u2d/

Comment: i dont get how to use this italian thing in command line :|

Answer (score 1):

This simple script is fast and works great except it converts every TAB character into 8 spaces. The number of spaces can be modified with the MORE /T option, but there is no way to preserve the TAB characters. Pass the file name (optionally with path) as the one and only argument.

```
@echo off
more %1 >%1.new
move /y %1.new %1 >nul
```

All that is needed is to read and echo each line. The FOR /F command is perfect, except it ignores empty lines. Here I use FINDSTR to prefix each line with the line number, followed by a `:`, thus preserving empty lines. Then I use search and replace to remove the number prefix. I must toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop to preserve any `!` that may appear. This script preserves TABs, but is limited to ~8191 bytes per line. It is also relatively slow. It will become very slow with very large files.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>%1.new (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" %1') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y %1.new %1 >nul
```

Finally, here is a hybrid batch/JScript solution that is very fast, and does not have any limitations that I am aware of.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
<%1 cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" >%1.new
move /y %1.new %1 >nul
exit /b

************* JScript portion **********/
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine());
}
```